# Datatables - wrap td to content

Tags: datatable, bootstrap-4

I have a table in which some of the columns contain very short data.
Example:
[image]

I want such columns to be smaller but the columnDefs doesn't work:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="my_table" class="table table-hover">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

and here's my jquery:

```
let table = $('#' + table_id).DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
        "order": order,
        "columnDefs": [
            {"width": "5%", "targets": [9,10,11]}
        ]
    });
```

I use Bootstrap4.

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) it should work. Are you sure you're targeting the correct columns? Anyways, being a payed plugin and since you're using the correct syntax, it's definitely a question for their forum. In general, asking for help with licenced software is neither popular nor effective on [SO], since nobody will buy a licence to answer questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so turns out what caused this was the fact that I also added search to each column using 'input'.

```
$('#' + table_id + ' tfoot th').each(function () {
        const title = $(this).text();
        if (title) {
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="search..."/>');
        }
    });
```

This made all columns the same width. **To fix this** I added 'style="width:100%"'.

```
$('#' + table_id + ' tfoot th').each(function () {
        const title = $(this).text();
        if (title) {
            $(this).html('<input style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="search..."/>');
        }
    });
```